# How to execute an oracle stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, ora-00900

I am using oracle 10g express edition. It has a nice ui for db developers. But i am facing some problems executing stored procedures.

Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure temp_proc is
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test');
end
```

it is created successfully. But when i execute:

`execute temp_proc;`

it shows **ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement**

So help needed here

Comment: That's valid for SQLPlus - how are you trying to run it?

Comment: First i opnen "Go To Database Home Page", then Home>SQL>SQL Commands. Then create procedure, then execute.

Comment: oracle 10g express edition 10.2....

Comment: What SQL IDE are you using - PLSQL Developer?  Toad?

Comment: i am not using any ide. It is a built in ui given in the oracle xe. But i found the solution.

begin
proc_name();
end

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`Execute` is sql*plus syntax .. try wrapping your call in begin .. end like this:

```
begin 
    temp_proc;
end;
```

(Although Jeffrey says this doesn't work in APEX .. but you're trying to get this to run in SQLDeveloper .. try the 'Run' menu there.)

Answer (score 5):

Both 'is' and 'as' are valid syntax. Output is *disabled* by default. Try a procedure that also enables output...

```
create or replace procedure temp_proc is
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test');
end;
```

...and call it in a PLSQL block...

```
begin
  temp_proc;
end;
```

...as SQL is non-procedural.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle 10g Express Edition ships with Oracle Application Express (Apex) built-in. You're running this in its SQL Commands window, which doesn't support SQL*Plus syntax.

That doesn't matter, because (as you have discovered) the BEGIN...END syntax does work in Apex.

Answer (score 1):

I use oracle 12 and it tell me that if you need to invoke the procedure then use **call** keyword.
In your case it should be:

```
begin
  call temp_proc;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Oracle SQL Developer (GUI)**, using 12c, also don't forget to enable the **DMBS Output** window (click **View => Dbms Output**, then click **"+"** sign, and select your *connection*), by default the window is not enabled.

[image: DBMS Output window]
[image: DBMS output window enabled]

The following syntax will then output to this window:

```
begin
  temp_proc
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to correct the syntax like this?:

```
create or replace procedure temp_proc AS
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test');
end;
```

Comment: What I see is that you have just changed IS to AS and added a semicolon at the end of 'end' keyword. Though addition of semicolon is fine but OP says compilation was successful so that cann't be the issue. The issue is that OP wasn't aware of how to execute proc which have already been addressed correctly in accepted answer. So this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply the following on the Command Window:

```
Connected to Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 
Connected as XXX@YYY


SQL> call temp_proc();
```

Or:

```
SQL> execute temp_proc();
```