# How to execute a stored procedure which has an output parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

This question answers about calling an Oracle stored procedure: [How to execute an oracle stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854427/how-to-execute-an-oracle-stored-procedure)

However I have a procedure which takes one IN and one OUT parameter. What should my test syntax in Oracle SQL Developer look like to define a variable, run a stored procedure, and output the result of that variable?

I'm trying this but declaring the variable gives me an error:

```
begin
xyz MY_TABLE.EMAIL_ADDRESS%TYPE := NULL;
myPackage.GetEmailForId('12345',xyz);
end;
```

Comment: Declarations go in the `declare` section of the block:
`declare
 xyz MY_TABLE.EMAIL_ADDRESS%TYPE := NULL; 
begin
  myPackage.GetEmailForId('12345',xyz);
end;`

Comment: I seem to see this is now running, but I'm not sure how to select `xyz` to see the value. Could you post a full example as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
declare
    xyz MY_TABLE.EMAIL_ADDRESS%TYPE; 
begin 
    myPackage.GetEmailForId('12345',xyz);
    dbms_output.put_line(xyz);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

> What should my test syntax in Oracle SQL Developer look like to define a variable, run a stored procedure, and output the result of that variable?

Create a unit test.

1. Go to `Tools` > `Unit Test` > `Select Current Repository` and follow the prompts to set up a unit test repository.
2. Go to `View` > `Unit Test` to open the Unit Testing view.
3. Right-click on tests and choose `Create test`.
4. Choose the connection and then pick the procedure you want to test.
5. Specify the test name and select `Create single with dummy implementation` then click `Next`.
6. Click 'Next' (you don't need any startup).
7. Specify the values for the parameters then click `Finish`.
8. The test should then appear in the `Unit Test` view and you can right-click and select `Run Test`.

[Oracle's documentation for unit tests is here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15846_01/doc.21/e15222/unit_testing.htm#RPTUG45000).

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, I'll check it out. Thanks