# Using 'exec' in Oracle trigger code

Tags: linux, oracle, shell

i tried to create a Oracle trigger, after the table is insert or update, touch a file in the Linux host.

so i create a shell script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch  /export/home/oracle/shell/a.txt
```

and modify the permission:

```
chmod +x test1.sh
```

then i use the sys login oracle and create a scheduler job like this:

```
SQL>  exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(job_name=>'test1',job_type=>'EXECUTABLE',job_action=>'/export/home/oracle/shell/test1.sh');
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

now i want to create a Oracle trigger and call this scheduler job like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_OAM_LOG
 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON OCS_CHARGE_OFF_AUTOMATION
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(job_name=>'test1');
END;
/
```

but error:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_OAM_LOG
  2   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON OCS_CHARGE_OFF_AUTOMATION
  3   FOR EACH ROW 
  4  BEGIN
  5   exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(job_name=>'test1');
  6  END;
  7  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show error
Errors for TRIGGER MY_OAM_LOG:

LINE/COL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2/7
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DBMS_SCHEDULER" when expecting one of the fol
lowing:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "DBMS_SCHEDULER" to continue.
```

i have search many solution,bu none of them are work.how do i deal with it?plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `exec` inside the the trigger code which is PL/SQL.  `exec` is an SQL*Plus command.  Remove `exec` and your code should be good:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_OAM_LOG
 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON OCS_CHARGE_OFF_AUTOMATION
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(job_name=>'test1');
END;
/
```

---

From [PL/SQL Command Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1009731):

> EXECUTE
>
> EXEC[UTE] statement
>
> Executes a single PL/SQL statement. The EXECUTE command is often
>   useful when you want to execute a PL/SQL statement that references a
>   stored procedure.

---

See also:

- [How to execute an oracle stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854427/how-to-execute-an-oracle-stored-procedure)