# Plsql to run Stored procedure with Custom types as Table

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

I have stored procedure

```
PROCEDURE getEmployees(i_employee_forms IN EMPFORMLIST_ID_TYPES, result OUT EMPLOYEELIST)


EMPFORMLIST_ID_TYPES as table of EMPFORM_ID_TYPE;
EMPLOYEELIST as table of EMPLOYEE;
```

I am trying to write plsql block to execute this.

Can some on hemp me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute an oracle stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854427/how-to-execute-an-oracle-stored-procedure)

Comment: @SudiptaMondal. This question is different. I am referring tables types where as the referenced question does not give such info

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing ? Its unclear from the question you have asked.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal. I am trying to execute the stored procedure with custom types as parameter. Theinput parameter and output parameter are not defualt ones. I am unsure how to declare and pass them to stored procedure. Could you help me

Comment: Please post the complete code that creates the types. Also, what have you tried and what is the issue with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
DECLARE
    employee_forms EMPFORMLIST_ID_TYPES;
    employee_list EMPLOYEELIST;
BEGIN
    employee_forms := EMPFORMLIST_ID_TYPES('variable1', 'variable2', 'variable3');

    getEmployees(employee_forms, employee_list);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you. EMPFORMLIST_ID_TYPES is table of EMPLOYEELIST_ID which has 2 fileds(Name, Id). Can you please help me with that

Comment: What exactly is `EMPLOYEELIST_ID`? A table? Please provide more details what exactly your problem is.