# Procedure is not executing

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOGINUPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN 
UPDATE 
(select e.status  from EmployeeTest E
INNER Join  SecurityTest S on S.SecurityID=E.EmployeeID and S.SecurityLevel<>'Admin'
INNER Join  LOGINTest    L on E.EmployeeID=L.LoginID and LastLogin < Add_Months(Cast(SysDate as date),25) and E.Status=1
) t
SET t.status = 0
END;


EXECUTE LOGINUPDATE;
```

Why I can't Execute this procedure ? Can anyone spot the issue ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: What happens when you execute it?  Does it give any error?  See if this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856749/259889

Basically your approach to executing procedure may be wrong.

Comment: Yes I get error of Invalid SQL command

Comment: This is **the same question** as [the one which you have just deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49549803/146325). It was a duplicate then and it is a duplicate now.

Comment: That won't even compile as shown. Are you running everything you've shown as one script - and how, through which client or application? (There is no semicolon at the end of the uodate, which probably won't work as per APC; and you may need a slash between `end` and `execute`, assuming you're using a client that can handle that - the error suggests not...)

Comment: `Cast(SysDate as date)` is unnecessary. `SYSDATE` is already a `DATE`