# Execute and test stored procedure in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I don't know how to execute or test this procedure. I'm new in that area. Thanks in advance.

Table Prices has id,price, datePrice and productId. Table Products has id, currentprice and name

```
        create or replace PROCEDURE "currentprice"
        (idproduct IN NUMBER) AS
        currentprice products.current_price%type;
        BEGIN
         SELECT price INTO currentprice 
         FROM prices
         WHERE productId=idprice AND datePrice=(select max(datePrice) FROM prices WHERE 
          productId=idprice AND datePrice<=SYSDATE);

          UPDATE products
          SET currentprice = currentprice 
          WHERE id=idproduct;
           END;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute an oracle stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854427/how-to-execute-an-oracle-stored-procedure)

Comment: Nope. I get error "no data found" after executed that

Comment: Oracle errors usually start with a code like `ORA`, `PLS` or `SP2`. How did you call it exactly, and what was the whole error message? The query of `prices` might fail with `no data found` if there was no price stored for the specified `idproduct` (or `productId` - was that a typo?)

Comment: OK. I figured out somehow where is my mistake. I get PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. Now I need to test this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Begin
 "currentprice"(1);
End;
/
```

`Commit`;

Execute with F5 in SQL Developer, then query your table data to see the new prices.

I recommend you rename your procedure to currentprice - no quotes...you'll save yourself a lot of trouble.

You can also browse to the procedure in SQL Developer and open it, then use the Execute button.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed procedure - no quotes. No data found again.

I have trigger which call that procedure

```
     create or replace TRIGGER currentprice2
       AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON Prices
       DECLARE
       s NUMBER:=priceproduct.id;
       BEGIN
        currentprice(s);
       END;
```

Also, I have package. Maybe I made mistake with package parameter id.

```
      create or replace PACKAGE priceproduct IS
      id products.id%TYPE;
      END priceproduct;
```